# "org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query" on sqlserver but ok on Oracle?

Tags: hibernate

Im porting an application from Oracle to SQLServer. This error occurs on the first attempt to access the database (org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query).

This is the (elided) accessing code :-

```
Session session = serviceLocator.getSessionFactory().openSession();

List<BaseTemplate> baseTemplateList = null;
Query query = null;
try
{       
   query = session.createQuery("from BaseTemplate");
   baseTemplateList = query.list();                   <<<<< Exception thrown here
}
etc
```

The Bean code :-

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.iontrading.reportserver.database.model.IBaseTemplate;

@Entity
@Table(name = "BASETEMPLATE")
public class BaseTemplate implements IBaseTemplate{

    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="TEMPLATENAME")    
    private String templateName;

@Id 
@GeneratedValue 
@Column(name = "TEMPLATEID")
@Override
/** {@inheritDoc} */
public Integer getId() { return id; }

@Override
/** {@inheritDoc} */
public void setId(Integer id) { this.id = id; }
```

...snip<>
    }
Table creation DDL
CREATE TABLE "dbo"."BASETEMPLATE"
(
   TEMPLATEID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   ...
   TEMPLATENAME VARCHAR(255)
)

Points that may or may not be relevant :-

1. This works fine if the database is Oracle.
2. The table name and the bean class name do not match but use @Table
3. The column names do not match the bean field names but use @Column
4. The primary key is a generated value.
5. The bean imports are JPA not hibernate.

? Any ideas why I get this exception or how I could get more information out of hibernate would be very useful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using JPA, the query style changes a bit, like

```
query = session.createQuery("select b from BaseTemplate");
```

What is the database schema you are using?  `dbo` is the default schema for the sql server. So, its better to define a schema your self and use it both oracle and sql server.